# How do I pass data to a flask form using pytest?

Tags: flask, pytest, flask-wtforms, flask-login

I am struggling passing data to a form using pytest.  I wish to pass the username and password to a login form.  Here is what I have tried:

conftest.py

```
import pytest
from wahoo_connect import init_app, db
from wahoo_connect.models import User

from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv('.flaskenv')

@pytest.fixture(scope='module')
def app():
    app = init_app()
    with app.app_context():
        db.create_all()
        user = User(username='testuser', email='test@gmail.com', forename='Test', surname='User', confirmed=True)
        user.set_password('testing')
        db.session.add(user)
        db.session.commit()
        yield app

@pytest.fixture(scope='module')
def client(app):
    return app.test_client()
```

this sets up a client fixture which is used by my test:

```
def test_index_page__logged_in(client):
    with client:
        formdata = {'username': 'testuser', 'password': 'testing', 'remember_me': False}
        client.post('/auth/login', data=formdata)
        assert current_user.username == 'testuser'
```

the route is defined in a blueprint as:

```
@auth_bp.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    # Login route logic goes here
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect(url_for('home_bp.index'))
    form = LoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user = User.query.filter_by(username=form.username.data).first()
        if user is None or not user.check_password(form.password.data):
            flash('Invalid username or password', 'warning')
            return redirect(url_for('auth_bp.login'))
        login_user(user, remember=form.remember_me.data)
        next_page = request.args.get('next')
        if not next_page or url_parse(next_page).netloc != '':
            next_page = url_for('home_bp.index')
        return redirect(next_page)
    return render_template('auth/login.html', title='Sign In', form=form)
```

and here is the form:

```
class LoginForm(FlaskForm):
    username = StringField('Username', validators=[DataRequired()])
    password = PasswordField('Password', validators=[DataRequired()])
    remember_me = BooleanField('Remember Me')
    submit = SubmitField('Sign In')
```

and the template:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
<div class="form-signin text-center">
    <form action="" method="post" novalidate>
        <h3>Please sign in</h3>
        <div class="form-floating">
            {{ form.username(type="text", class="form-control", id="floatingInput", placeholder="Username") }}
            {% for error in form.username.errors %}
                <span style="color: red;">[{{ error }}]</span>
            {% endfor %}
            <label for="floatingInput">{{ form.username.label.text }}</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-floating">
            {{ form.password(type="password", class="form-control", id="floatingPassword", placeholder="Password") }}
            {% for error in form.password.errors %}
                <span style="color: red;">[{{ error }}]</span>
            {% endfor %}
            <label for="floatingPassword">{{ form.password.label.text }}</label>
        </div>

        <div class="checkbox mb-3">
        <label>
            {{ form.remember_me() }} {{ form.remember_me.label.text }}
        </label>
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">{{ form.submit.label.text }}</button>
        {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
    </form>
</div>
<p class="text-center">Forgot Your Password? <a href="{{ url_for('auth_bp.reset_password_request') }}">Click to Reset</a></p>
<p class="text-center pt-3"><a href="{{ url_for('auth_bp.register') }}">Create an Account</a></p>
{% endblock %}
```

I can see the data before the "if form.validate_on_submit():" statement in the view and it is correct, but I can never get beyond this point in the submission process.  I seem to be missing something!

Thank you

Martyn

Answer (score 1):

It seems that I was missing an important flag:

```
WTF_CSRF_ENABLED = False
```

it now works!